# Am I using random.shuffle wrong or is this a bug?

Tags: python, random, shuffle

So I'm shuffling a list before I split it. it's a list of numbers read from a file so the list is actually a list of strings, but they're numbers:

```
streams = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```

now, the code I run, simply shuffles the list:

```
print(streams, type(streams[0]))
import random
random.shuffle(streams)
```

I'm using Python 3.6.4 by the way. Here's the error I get:

```
C:\src>python cli.py
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
 <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "....py", line 3, in split_randomized_list
    random.shuffle(streams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\random.py", line 275, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

This says to me that it can't shuffle lists made up of numbers in string format? Is that right? Is that a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @U9-Forward what version of python are you on?

Comment: I don't think the version matters, my version is python-3.6.0

Comment: You're not shuffling a list.  You're trying to a shuffle a string.  A string is not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be:

```
streams = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
new_streams = streams.split(',')
import random
random.shuffle(new_streams)
print(new_streams)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've managed to replicate your bug, I've changed your streams to a list.

```
streams_old = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
streams = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

print(streams, type(streams[0]))
import random
random.shuffle(streams)
```

Comment: oh, thanks I guess I assumed it was a list when it wasn't

Comment: @LegitStack it was very misleading to put `streams = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']` in your question...